# Junit is failing for Ldap Connection

Tags: junit, ldap, mockito

Using Spring boot i have passed ldap details in YML file.Using controller calling service > Service Impl.I have written Junit which is failing.It is trying to get connection to LDAP server.I need to mock LDAP Server.Can you please let me know how i can mock LDAP server for Junit.

Comment: Although you have said this is a Unit question, there doesn't appear to be any Unit tests in the question.
Could you show the code that is important and the error results, please?

Comment: @Test
    public void testGetProfileSuccess() throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String id = "20573";
        File file = ResourceUtils.getFile(this.getClass().getResource("/LdapUser.json"));
        LdapUserProfileResponse ldapUserInFile = objectMapper.readValue(file, LdapUserProfileResponse.class);
        Mockito.when(UserProfileRepository.findById(id)).thenReturn(Optional.empty());
       LdapUserProfileResponse actualUser = userServiceImpl.getUserProfile(id);
        Assert.assertEquals(ldapUserInFile.getStaffNameFR(), "actual");}

Comment: Please edit the question to include the code and other information, rather than just leaving it in comments.